# Linkedlist or recursively calling hash map

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a list of students with me. aaa is leader for bbb and ddd. bbb is leader for eee and eee is leader for fff.

```
Students   leader     groupStudent
aaa         --        [bbb,ddd]
bbb         aaa       [eee]
ccc         ---        ---
ddd         aaa       []
eee         bbb       [fff]
fff         eee       []
```

I want to implement this in JAVA. to display as graphical representation like below.

```
     fff
      |
     eee 
      |
aaa--bbb---ddd
```

I have huge numbers of students and each student can mentor any other students. Which data structure can be used to display diagram shown above.? I am thinking of hash map which has key value pair, aaa has [bbb,ddd].

Comment: I would suggest to get more help that you give shot at coding your idea "hash map which has key value pair, aaa has [bbb,ddd]," and post that code.

Answer (score 1):

[image]You have got it in your opening statement itself.

```
aaa is leader for bbb and ddd. bbb is leader for eee and eee is leader for fff.
```

This is a hierarchy of information. Tree datastructure is your best fit here. `aaa` would be a node in the tree with `bbb` and `ddd` as its children and hence forth.

If somewhere down the line, if you have a requirement to show all those who report to `bbb`, then Tree datastructure helps you. All you have do is traverse its children instead of nested HashMap traversals.

Comment: Pavan: But here in tree, we can have 2 children. But If the aaa is mentor for 3 students more. Then how would I solve as tree might not hold good. Below can also be a posibility


    fff
      |
     eee 
      |
aaa--bbb---ddd--ggg-hhh

Comment: A Tree has no restriction that it should contain only two nodes. You can always have a node that has 3 children or even 4 children. There is no restriction. The only restriction is that there is no loop.